# amplitude compensation after filtering and mixing audio

Tags: frequency-spectrum, sound, filtering

I am working on a mixer which lets me mix dry and wet signal in a user defined ratio. Wet signal is basically just the all pass filtered signal. The mixing takes place in frequency domain and so does the filtering. So the requirement here is, after mixing I have to compensate for amplitude loss, i.e. the output signal should have same peak value over a frame as input signal.

So basically

```
output= x*wet +(1-x)*dry;
```

where dry is the input signal and wet is the output of filter, and all the signals are in frequency domain. x is a scalar ratio(0 to 1).

Is there any way to apply this compensation. I tried to multiply by ratio of RMS values of input and output
i.e. `output = RMS(input)/RMS(output) *output` (again everything in frequency domain)

but even this doesn't produce the desired result. (I am seeing meters in audacity after processing in aforementioned manner).